# Does the Graph/Teams API give access to read Recap / AI notes?

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams

I am using Teams Premium and I can see the Recap / AI note in the UI; but, I am unable to get these with the Graph API.

I would like to be able to get the Recap / AI notes as I can transcripts.
[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings/{id}/transcripts](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings/%7Bid%7D/transcripts)

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is currently not supported by Graph API

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported by Graph API